# Do I have to link my app to Firebase in both Android Studio and Firebase Console web?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

I want to set up Crashlytics in my app and I have searched for information and first I have to link my app to a Firebase project.

I have seen that this can be done inside Android Studio itself (I have seen that inside Android Studio if I go to Tools->Firebase->Crashlytics->Get started with Firebase Crashlytics, there are 3 steps to follow to link my app -> Step 1: "Connect your app with firebase", Step 2: Add Crashlytics SDK and plugin to your app, Step 3: "Force a test crash to finish setup", Step 4: "Next Steps".

But I have seen also that if I go to the firebase console on the web, there is also like a guide to follow and fill in information within the Firebase web with 3 steps -> Step 1: "Register app", Step 2: "Download config file", Step 3: "Add Firebase SDK" Step 4: "More Steps".

Do I have to link my app to Firebase in both Android Studio and Firebase Console web? Or do I have to link it in only one place and it doesn't matter if it's in Android Studio itself or it is on the Firebase Console web?

Answer (score 0):

It is never required to use Android Studio with Firebase.  You can do everything through the console and any code editor of your choice.  Android Studio integration is just a convenience for many developers.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to register your app on firebase (i.e enter application name, package name and SHA) then download the config file place inside the app folder install the dependencies of firebase and crashlytics after that you are done

Comment: I have seen that the SHA is optional. I don´t know if I have to fill it or not. I will use Firebase only for crashlytics. My app is already published on the Play Store, so I will integrate the firebase crashlytics and the update the app, so should I use that SHA?

Answer (score 0):

To make a connection between a Firebase project and your Android app, two things need to happen:

1. Your Firebase project needs to know about the Android app that connects to it.
2. The Android app itself needs to know what Firebase project it needs to connect to.

The Firebase Assistant in Android Studio can be used to take care of both of these steps.

Alternatively, you can do both in the Firebase console, where they are step 1 and 2 in process you've seen/mentioned.

So you can follow either one of the processes you outlined, but there's no need to do both.

Comment: I have decided to use the firebase console, but I have seen that there is something called SHA-1 (it is optional). I don´t know if I have to fill it or not. I will use Firebase only for crashlytics. My app is already published on the Play Store, so I will integrate the firebase crashlytics and the update the app, so should I use that SHA?

Comment: You can skip it for now as it is for security purpose so that you can restrict API usage based on SHA and nobody can reuse your API keys